# How to call a function inside a function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBAction func first(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("Hello World")
}

@IBAction func second(sender: Anyobject) {
// I need to call function first here. 
}
```

I need to use one function inside another, because the sender type is Anyobject, I don't know how to call it.

Comment: Why do you want to call an `IBAction` from another `IBAction`?

Comment: The code in the first function is actually complicated, it would be more convenient if I can call the second directly from inside the first

Comment: Yogesh, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: FYI - you can make normal functions (using `func`) that are not bound to an `IBAction`. You will want to use an `IBAction` for firing button presses only.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried

```
func first(){
    println("Hello World")
}

@IBAction func second(sender: AnyObject) {
    first()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure about the type of control,it should be UIControl object like`UIButton`,`UISegmentControl` etc, then change the sender to that type.

If both function's parameter are same you can do like

```
@IBAction func second(sender: UIButton) {//it sure that you are clikcing UIButton
    self.first(sender)//if here also a button, else create the control and pass.
}
```

But why you want first function as @IBAction? If it is not attached to any control please make it as normal function